# How to read a file and copy certain numbers from the use of keywords into excel or another txt file?

Tags: python, excel, readfile

I have a file that I am currently just manually transferring the numbers from certain sections into excel and was hoping to instead write them into a txt file or directly into excel.

The original file is a sum file (although essentially is just a txt file)

And part way through the file it has a number of CP's I want to obtain the v= value and G= value. And then have them in array on a txt file.For example in the file it has this printed half way down:

[image]

```
  import os
  from glob import glob

  list_of_files = glob('*.sum')  # get list of all .sum files

  for file in list_of_files:
      with open(file, 'r') as f: 
          content = f.read()

          # not sure how to find the keyword 'i.e. G=' and print what is 
          # behind 
          g = content        

          f = open("excelsheet.txt", "w+")   
          f.write(content)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) and [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) packages to find the lines you need.

Read in a file as you have shown. I'm testing my scipt with the following "text file"

```
text = '''
CP# 1
V = -3.02132E+02
G = -5.15550E+12
K = -9.84693E+06
L =  1.16878E+06

CP# 2
V =  5.53209E+08
G =  6.06581E+08
K = -7.41506E+18
L = -9.87995E+02

CP# 3
V =  5.47807E+08
G = -5.03863E+00
K = -1.09701E+12
L = -5.30051E+09
'''
```

Now that you have the file loaded, use the `re` package to find the matches you are looking for. You can use the link above to learn more about the syntax.

```
h_matches = re.findall(r'CP#\s\d', text)
v_matches = re.findall(r'(?<=V\s=)\s+[0-9+-E]+', text)
g_matches = re.findall(r'(?<=G\s=)\s+[0-9+-E]+', text)

headers  = [h for h in h_matches]
v_values = [m for m in v_matches]
g_values = [m for m in g_matches]
```

Once you have all the matches, use `csv` to write out the data to a csv file.

```
with open('example.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(['header', 'V', 'G'])

    for h, v, g in zip(headers, v_values, g_values):
        writer.writerow([h, v, g])
```

Below is the output in `example.csv`

```
header,V,G
CP# 1, -3.02132E+02, -5.15550E+12
CP# 2,  5.53209E+08,  6.06581E+08
CP# 3,  5.47807E+08, -5.03863E+00
```

If you are looking to write into an existing excel sheet, you can checkout [`xlsxwriter`](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/)